# How to disable normal panning and use shift + click to pan ? d3/js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am working on a force layout graph and i wish to press shift and click to pan. This is so i have the ability to select multiple nodes by highlighting them with one click.

How would i go about disabling the ordinary click and hold to pan so i can use that to select and then use shift + click to pan around my network ?

Comment: Set the handlers to `null`, e.g. `element.on("mousedown", null);`.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff but that wouldnt let me highlight the nodes with a click then would it ? And how would i go about using ctrl + click to pan ?

Comment: You would need to install a new handler function that does that.